# Data Trigger won't trigger background change

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a TouchListBoxItem and i'm trying to change the background of per "box" when a certain data is "false"

I want to change the background color of certain items in the touchlistbox and these items has a boolean data that should trigger if it should change background

```
<c:TouchListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style
        TargetType="ListBoxItem"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource noMouseOverListBoxItemStyle}">
        <Setter
            Property="FocusVisualStyle"
            Value="{StaticResource FocusVisualStyle}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding IsGroupingItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
            Value="False">
             <Setter
                Property="Background"
                Value="{StaticResource ItemBackgroundColorBrush}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</c:TouchListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Added the Style.Triggers and if the IsGroupingItem is False then it should change the Background to ItemBackgroundColorBrush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
{Binding IsGroupingItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}
```

expects an `IsGroupingItem` property in the ListBoxItem class, which it doesn't have.

Bind to a property of the actual item object by

```
Binding="{Binding IsGroupingItem}"
```

Also make sure that `IsGroupingItem` is actually a public property, not a field, and that it fires the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Thank you, This worked! This deserves an upvote but I'm still a noob here at stackoverflow